# What is the domain of the function $f(x)$ and what is the value of the parameter $a$ for which the function is always positive?

Tags: calculus, functions

I have the following function:

$f: D \rightarrow \mathbb{R},$ $f(x)= \dfrac{ln(x+a)}{\sqrt{x}}$

$a \in \mathbb{R}$

And I am asked $2$ things:

- Find the domain $D$ of the function $f(x)$.
- Find the values of $a$ such that $f(x) > 0, \forall x \in
     \mathbb{R}$.

Concerning point $1$, I applied the following conditions:

$$x > 0 \Rightarrow x \in (0, + \infty)$$

$$x+a>0 \Rightarrow x > -a \Rightarrow x \in (-a, + \infty)$$

Combining these $2$ conditions, I got:

$$x \in (max(-a, 0), + \infty)$$

However, when I checked my textbook, I found that the answer they have listed is this:

$$x \in \bigg ( \dfrac{-a+ |a| }{2}, + \infty \bigg )$$

Can somebody explain why are these $2$ answers equivalent (that is, **if** I didn't do any mistakes and they are indeed equivalent)?

And concerning the $2 ^ {nd}$ point, I tried to find the derivative thinking that I would use it to find the minimum/minima point/points and choose values of $a$ such that those minima are $>0$. But the derivative I found is a whole mess with both $x's$ and $a's$ and I didn't know how to handle it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\frac {-a+|a|} 2$ is same as $\max (-a,0)$. Just consider the case $a \geq 0$ and $a<0$ to verify this.

The second question does not make sense. Whatever $a$ is, there are values of $x$ for which $f(x)$ is not defined.

However if the question is to find $a$ such that $f(x)>0$ for ll $x \in D$ then the answer is $a \geq 1$.

[We want $x+a >1$ whenever $x >\max (-a,0)$. It is easy to see that this will not hold if $a<0$. So take $a \geq 0$. Then the condition is $x>1-a$ whenever $x >0$. In particular this gives $\frac 1 n > 1-a$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$. Letting $n \to \infty$ we get $0 \geq 1-a$ or $a \geq 1$. Conversely if $a \geq 1$ it is easy to see that $f(x) >0$ for all $x \in D$].

Comment: How did you arrive at the answer of the second question, $a\ge 1$?

Comment: @user1502 I have added some details.

Answer (score 0):

If $0\geq -a$, then $a\geq 0$ from which follows
$$\frac{-a+|a|}{2}=\frac{-a+a}{2}=0=\max(0,-a)$$
In the other hand, if $-a\geq 0$, then $a\leq 0$ and hence
$$\frac{-a+|a|}{2}=\frac{-a+(-a)}{2}=-a=\max(0,-a)$$

Answer (score 0):

If $a\geqslant0$, then $\max\{-a,0\}=0=\frac{-a+\lvert a\rvert}2$. And if $a<0$, $\max\{-a,0\}=-a=\lvert a\rvert=\frac{-a+\lvert a\rvert}2$. So, your solution and the given solution are the same.

Concerning the second question, note that $\frac{\log(x+a)}{\sqrt x}>0\iff\log(x+a)>0$. It is easy to deduce from this that the answer to the second question is $a\in[1,\infty)$.

Comment: You say it is easy to deduce. Can you please elaborate a little. I tried solving it but I always get $x \in (1, + \infty) $. If possible, can you show me your deduction or at least guide me in the right direction?

Comment: If $a<1$, then there is some $x>0$ such that $x+a<1$. For such a $x$, $\log(x+a)<0$. And if $a\geqslant1$, you always have $x+a\geqslant 1$ when $x>0$, and therefore $\log(x+a)\geqslant0$.

Answer (score 0):

For the domain we need

- $x+a>0 \implies x>-a$
- $x\ge 0$

therefore

$$\dfrac{-a+ |a| }{2}$$

works since it is equal to $0$ for $a\ge 0$ and it is equal to $-a$ for $a<0$.

For the second point we need

- $x+a>1 \implies x>1-a$
- $x\ge 0$